# Tricky Assembly language syntax interface with Fortran77

Tags: assembly, x86, fortran

My OS: Windows 7,32 Bit, Intel Centrino Core*2 Duo, Toshiba A 205 Satellite,386 Pentium Laptop.
My binUtils: GNU Assembler Version 2.9.4  using BFD version 2.9.4.
 
I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4 Version

The following error displays on the screen.

```
Program received signal sigsegv: segmentation fault-invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:

    *#0 0x6f8aecb4 
    #1 0x6f89d642 
    #2 0x401138*
```

Flower.f:

```
          CHARACTER W*1
          CALL SCREEN (6) 
    005   OPEN (1,FILE='FLOWER.DAT')
    030   READ (1,021,END=035)  IR,IC,IP
          CALL PIXEL (1,IR,IC)
          GO TO 030
    035   CLOSE (1)
    021   FORMAT (I3,I3)
    C      READ (*,’(A\)’) W
          READ (1,022) W
    022   FORMAT (A1)
          CALL SCREEN (3)
          END
```

```
.global _screen_ 
_screen_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Movb    $0,%ah
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Int     $0x10 #int 16
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $04
.global _pixel_ 
_pixel_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Movb    $12,%ah
Les     14(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Les     10(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%dx
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%cx
Int     $0x10 #int 16
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $12*
```

I have tried in so many ways but it is futile.

I don't know the fault where it is lies and what is the solution? Is there any alternate?

Comment: `les  6(%ebp), %bx` is almost certainly the first fault. You can’t load ES on a protected mode OS. The next instruction then uses EBX as an address, when it is almost certainly garbage. And if you somehow manage to get past both of those, then `int 0x10` isn’t going to work on Windows.

Comment: Is this some old DOS assembly? How did you get the assembly? What is the relation to the Fortran code?

Comment: Yes it is old DOS assembly. Written 33 years back for DOS Fortran77 4.0Version of Microsoft.

Comment: Dear prl, thanks for your early response. Please guide/help me to solve my above said troubles. What is the solution and what is the alternate to the above mentioned my troubles? If any modifications required, what are they? The above mentioned Fortran,Assembly routines written about 33 years back. In between I am very busy with my private jobs. After retirement I am again trying to continue in this line. From the last 3 years I am trying to solve my above mentioned problems with Assembly language.

Comment: Dear Vladimir F,Thanks for your earl response.Yes it is old DOS assembly 5.0 Version. Written 33 years back for DOS Fortran77, 4.0 Version of Microsoft.Call Pixel,Call screen both are assembly routines related to Fortran77 calling subroutines to Flower.f.

Comment: I am anxiously waiting for guidance/help to solve my above mentioned troubles facing with Assembly language routines interface to Fortran77. A lot of astronomy research work is pending to solve.It is life time work.

Comment: if it is possible then I am trying to update my windows7 into windows10 quickly. If I am going to update the same error repeating on windows10 also. That is why I am trying to solve with the same windows7 version.

Comment: Dear prl, I tried that one also,changed bx in to ebx,but it is not working.

Comment: If any one try to send their code for the pixel.asm routine as example, I want to try and learn.That is the only method to learn fastly.

Comment: i don't want to argue,because unnecessary time wasting to all of you.I know your time is very precious. I am again request all of you please send me a solution with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly looks very much like a blind translation of 16-bit asm to 32-bit.  AFAIK, `int 16` interface only works from 16-bit programs.  You need to find the 32-bit api if you want to persue this, or else make a proper 16-bit program and use whatever compatibility windows has to move forward...

Also, `screen` and `pixel` both seem to want far pointers as arguments, which you then use as 16-bit far pointers.

Comment: OK,I am agreed with you.What is the solution to this? I am not blaming you, how to solve? Is there any modifications required to my above mentioned Assembly routines? If required what the exact/correct syntax? I forgot most of the Assembly language and also ready to learn again. Please guide me further to solve my problems regarding assembly routines. I am going to do some tedious astronomy research work in this regard I am trying to contact experts like you. There is no particular manual/reference guide to GAS,GFortran compilers for NetBeans IDE.Detailed help also not available online.

Comment: My original assembly,Fortran77 routines were 33 years back in DOS.In between I am in private jobs. After retirement again I am trying to continue in the same line. It is the only error obtained while running the exe file in windows mode. All other errors are nullified. EXE file also generated but run time error troubling me. If any possibility please guide/help me to solve my above cited trouble. I am not demanding it is only request. Because I don't want to waste your valuable time.

Comment: A lot of astronomy work is available for my life time. If GOD permits me I want to do some work as early as possible. I am mostly depending on  experts like you.

Comment: You need to find a versions of your graphics library compatible with whatever your current environment is, or find out how your current environment works, and write a simple graphics library for it.   There are a lot to choose from.